# Complex RDD types to simple array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, apache-spark, join

When I write out every line of my complex RDD, I do not get the values.

How can I see those values or even convert every line to the array, because now my type is Array[(String, (Array[String], Array[String]))].

```scala
scala> joined.foreach(println)
(8,([Ljava.lang.String;@2fe328b9,[Ljava.lang.String;@7df60197))
(8,([Ljava.lang.String;@7b74541e,[Ljava.lang.String;@7df60197))
(60,([Ljava.lang.String;@7c9f2683,[Ljava.lang.String;@4a8f6f49))
(60,([Ljava.lang.String;@7383536,[Ljava.lang.String;@4a8f6f49))
(60,([Ljava.lang.String;@5eb5556b,[Ljava.lang.String;@4a8f6f49))
(60,([Ljava.lang.String;@5b9bdb00,[Ljava.lang.String;@4a8f6f49))
(60,([Ljava.lang.String;@6adf021d,[Ljava.lang.String;@4a8f6f49))
(60,([Ljava.lang.String;@2c080bf5,[Ljava.lang.String;@4a8f6f49))
(60,([Ljava.lang.String;@58620d12,[Ljava.lang.String;@4a8f6f49))
(60,([Ljava.lang.String;@5da48ec5,[Ljava.lang.String;@4a8f6f49))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that 'joined' is your RDD:

```
joined.map(record => (record._1, record._2._1.mkString(", "), record._2._2.mkString(", "))).foreach(println)
```

I would like to raise one issue. When you iterate over an RDD (foreach) and invoke the println api, you're actually executing it on the Executor (remote worker on the cluster). You will not see those prints in the Master (Driver) console, unless you are running in Local[] mode of course.

Comment: Oh okay. But I get an error over the mkString. What is that?

```scala
scala> joined.map(record => (record._1, record._2.mkString(", "), record._3.mkString(", "))).foreach(println)
<console>:27: error: value mkString is not a member of (Array[String], Array[String])
       joined.map(record => (record._1, record._2.mkString(", "), record._3.mkString(", "))).foreach(println)
                                                  ^
```

Comment: Edited, please review